# Cant import crash file in XCode 6.3?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, xcode6

I can't able to either import a .crash file or drag and drop the .crash file in Devices -> Logs area in XCode 6.3.. Really confused with this.. Any idea would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. GO to the Xcode and click Window -> Devices Menu
2. Then select your device after that you can see search bar in left bottom side
3. Then you can see uparrow button near by search bar that will open the Logs area of your app.